# What is the significance of a 0-length array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[0],b[4][0];
    printf("%d %d ",sizeof(a),sizeof(b));
}
//output
0 0
```

what is the significance of `a[0]` , why also 2d array of size 0 is allowed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither C nor C++ allow arrays of zero length, so your program is ill-formed.

(E.g. C++11, 8.3.4/1: "[the array size] shall be greater than zero".)

(As one point of rationale: An array of zero length would be tricky and confusing to reconcile with the requirement that each object have a unique address.)

As @sidyll points out, zero-length arrays are available as an [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) in GCC.

Comment: it is not giving error in gcc compiler ubuntu 10.04

Comment: @user1044137: There are many, many, many ways to write both C and C++ programs that are ill-formed and for which you receive no diagnostic. For that matter, my GCC says `warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array`. You should always enable all warnings.

Comment: Why are you compiling a **C** program from a **C** question with a **C++** compiler and posting a **C++** standard excerpt?

Comment: @sidyll: This used to be tagged C++; check the edit log.

Comment: @sidyll: GCC also says `warning: ISO C forbids zero-size array` for all three versions of C.

Comment: I know it was C++, but the incorrect usage of this dirty language to refer to C makes me "one of these days I'm going to cut you into little pieces, C++". Oh man this drives me crazy. Ok, sorry. Back to the business: Strangely enough I didn't receive any warning, neither in Clang nor GCC

Comment: @sidyll: You need the `-pedantic` option to enable strict conformance checks. For new projects I would recommend `-W -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -pedantic`; probably adorned with `-std=c99`. Ditto for C++, but without the "write-strings" (which is automatic).

Comment: I would recommend some `-Wno-...` options after `-Wall -Wextra`. gcc includes some nonsensical stuff that spuriously triggers all the time on correct programs and even forces you to shun best-practices in certain cases if you want to shut up the warnings (e.g. you cannot use the universal zero-initializer for opaque types, `{0}`).

Answer (score 3):

You'll find your answer in [The GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)

If you are using  c99

> - Flexible array members are written as contents[] without the 0.
> - Flexible array members have incomplete type, and so the sizeof operator may not be applied. As a quirk of the original implementation of zero-length arrays, sizeof evaluates to zero.
> - Flexible array members may only appear as the last member of a struct that is otherwise non-empty.
> - A structure containing a flexible array member, or a union containing such a structure (possibly recursively), may not be a member of a structure or an element of an array. (However, these uses are permitted by GCC as extensions.

And of course, how they can be useful:

> Zero-length arrays are allowed in GNU C. They are very useful as the last element of a structure which is really a header for a variable-length object:
>
> ```
> struct line {
>    int length;
>    char contents[0];
>  };
>
> struct line *thisline = (struct line *)
>    malloc (sizeof (struct line) + this_length);
>  thisline->length = this_length;
> ```

Comment: In C11 and in C99, `sizeof` is not always a compile-time operator (that was only in C89).

Answer (score 1):

There is not much use as given in your example, but zero size arrays were frequently used in structures where the last element was dynamically sized:

```
struct {
     int    some_fixed_data [N_FIXED];
     float  more_fixed_size_data [F_FIXED];
     int    n_variable_elements;
     long   variable_elements [0];  // allocated based on item above
} s;

int curlen = sizeof s + sizeof long * s.n_variable_elements;
```

The use of a zero length array is:

1)  `variable_elements` has an address (despite someone's answer)
2)  it also has array semantics
3)  computing the dynamic size of the array is simplified

Unfortunately, some compilers (MSC) would throw a hissy fit over such a construction and force a lesser, appeasing, technically incorrect reformulation:

```
struct {
     int    some_fixed_data [N_FIXED];
     float  more_fixed_size_data [F_FIXED];
     int    n_variable_elements;
     long   variable_elements [1];  // allocated based on item above
} s;

int curlen = sizeof s + sizeof long + (s.n_variable_elements - 1);
```

Think of a zero size array as a placeholder.  There is little need to do that anymore, unless you are forced to use `C` which is the case on many embedded environments.